# How to ensure correct order of AWS SES events?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns, amazon-ses

I'm using AWS SES for sending emails. To track email delivery status information I have followig pipeline:

```
SES Config set -> SNS -> SQS -> Lambda -> Our system
```

Sometimes the events comes in wrong order. For example the event `Send` comes 30 seconds later after event `Delivery`, so in our system is the status `Delivery` replaced by `Send`.

I tried to set the SNS topic and SQS queue as FIFO. But in SES config set it is not possible to add SNS FIFO topic as destination. AWS says: `FIFO topics are not supported.`

The SES is located in different account than SNS, but I believe, that this has no effect.

Maybe I can remove the SQS, the lambda is probably fast enough, so it does not need the queue. But anyway, the standard SNS is high-throughput, best-effort delivery, so it does not keep the order.

I would like to solve this issue on the AWS side. How can I configure the AWS, so the events (resp. lambda) are fired in correct order? Does the SES publish the events in specific order?

Comment: Keep in mind that regular SQS queues also do not guarantee order. Have you checked if there is depth in your SQS queue? If so, that could be the reason you're seeing events out of order.

Comment: I am aware that the standard SQS does not guarantee order. That's the reason why I tried to use FIFO SNS and FIFO SQS, but these are not supported by SES events. If the depth represents the number of messages that are currently in the queue and available for processing, then yes, it is possible that there are several messages in the queue in one moment.